# What kind of file is cURL looking for when specifying --with-ssl?

Tags: curl, openssl, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile cURL for ARM 32. I'm able to compile it perfectly without SSL but I need HTTPS. To compile cURL with SSL, you just add the `--with-ssl` flag to the `./configure` call and then `./make`. That looks in the default place. However, since I'm cross compiling, I also need to cross compile OpenSSL for arm, which I have also done successfully. Where I'm having trouble is getting them to talk.

You can specify where you want the compiler to look for OpenSSL by doing `--with-ssl=/path/to/OpenSSL`. What kind of files is it looking for there? I'm aware that it can't just be "static libraries", that's why you have to compile OpenSSL with `shared` in the Configure command.

When I do this, I get `.so` files in the directory after I run `make` in OpenSSL. **Are the .so files what the compiler is looking for**? If so, why isn't cURL able to find OpenSSL?

OpenSSL configure command:

`CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- ./Configure linux-armv4 \
--prefix=/home/[redacted]/usr/local/openssl \
--openssldir=/home/[redacted]/usr/local/openssl \
shared`

cURL configure command:

`./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi \
--prefix=/home/[redacted]/usr/local \
--with-ssl=/home/[redacted]/usr/local/openssl`

After that just doing `make` for both.

Comment: when configure fails, *always* inspect `config.log` to learn about the details of the failures. curl's configure is just trying to ĺink with a small program that uses an openssl function...

Comment: Looks like you are missing "--target" option in configure of curl. In general curl expects openssl header file for compilation and ".so" for linking. So you need to specify "CFLAGS" for includes and "LDFLAS" & "LIBS" for linking libraries. Did you already checked http://www.matteomattei.com/how-to-cross-compile-curl-library-with-ssl-and-zlib-support/ ?